# How to log out and clear cookies after jsonwebtoken expires?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cookies, jwt, mern

Since the lifetime of JWT token is 15 seconds, I want to clear the cookie after that time. But I don't know how to do it properly.  Does it need to be done on the server side or can it be done on the client side? **Code with description below**

Using `mongoose` I create a user model and add a JWT token to it.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, process.env.JWTPRIVATEKEY, {expiresIn: "15s"})
  return token
};

const User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);

module.exports = { User }
```

---

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const { User } = require('../models/User');

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    const token = user.generateAuthToken();
    res.status(200).send({ data: token, message: "Logging in is successful" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal Server Error' })
  }
});
```

`data: token` This is the key issued by JWT. Recall that this is the JWT token that is created when a user is created. See the previous code

---

Next is a simple form where I make a request and receive a token in response, which I store in cookies

```
import { Cookies } from "react-cookie";
    
const cookies = new Cookies();
    
const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
  setData({ ...data, [input.name]: input.value });
};
    
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
   try {
     const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/auth";
     const { data: res } = await axios.post(url, data);
     cookies.set('token', res.data);
   } catch (error) {}
       
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input type="email" name={"email"} value={data.email} onChange={handleChange} required placeholder={"Email"} />
  <input type="password" name={"password"} value={data.password} onChange={handleChange} required placeholder={"Password"} />
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

And this is the JWT token I mentioned above.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would check if the JWT token has expired on the client side before running any requests that need it using `jwt.verify()`.

```
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
    /*
      err = {
        name: 'TokenExpiredError',
        message: 'jwt expired',
        expiredAt: 1408621000
      }
    */
  }
});
```

Inside the `if (err)`, you would handle invalidating the user’s session, such as deleting the expired token from their cookies and redirecting them to your login form.

Comment: And the token used to validate the jwt should be taken from the cookie? And then perform the verify jwt-token? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you’ve got it. You would retrieve token from the cookie using `cookies.get(‘token’)` and then perform the verification using `jwt.verify()`.